# Close incomplete href tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to close this kind of string:

```
$link = 'Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com';

echo $link;
```

How to fix the incomplete href tag? I want it to be:

```
$link = 'Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com"></a>'; // no value between <a> tag is alright.
```

I don't want to use `strip_tags()` or `htmlentities()` because i want it to be displayed as a working link.

Comment: What result are you getting right now?

Comment: only dealing with `<a>` tags?

Comment: What kind of input can be present? On strings like you provided?

Comment: $link = 'Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Label</a>';

Comment: the href tag is coming from mysql data, it's messing the succeeding display

Comment: Yes, dealing with a href for now. I think regex can handle this?

Comment: pls be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really good at regex but you can do a workaround using `DOMDocument`. Example:

```
$link = 'Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com';

$output = '';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($link);
libxml_clear_errors();
// the reason behind this is the HTML parser automatically appends `<p>` tags on lone text nodes, which is weird
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $output .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}

echo htmlentities($output);
// outputs:
// Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
```

Comment: @kimbarcelona sure tol no prob

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the data as you pull it from mysql.
Add to your code that gets the data from mysql something like:

```
...
$link = < YOUR MYSQL VALUE > . '"></a>';
...
```

Or you can run a query on your database to update the values, appending the string:

```
"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you might be interested in a Regex solution, so here's what I was able to come up with:

```
$link = 'Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com';

// Pattern matches <a href=" where there the string ends before a closing quote appears.
$pattern = '/(<a href="[^"]+$)/';

// Perform the regex search
$isMatch = (bool)preg_match($pattern, $link);

// If there's a match, close the <a> tag
if ($isMatch) {
    $link .= '"></a>';
}

// Output the result
echo $link;
```

Outputs:

```
Hello, welcome to <a href="www.stackoverflow.com"></a>
```